# `mtry` in R language `ranger`

Tags: r, random-forest, r-ranger

Which of the following understanding is true?

- The number of features that we can use per tree (we bootstrap a subset of features)
- The number of features that we use for each split

With equivalent function `RandomForestClassifier.max_features` in Python package `scikit-learn`, the first understanding is true. What is the situation in R language?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`mtry` in `ranger` and `randomForest` is the number of features, randomly sampled, to split at each node.

Comment: Normally, the splitting rule is something like "x1 >= c". If `mtry` larger than 2, does the splitting rule becomes something like "x1 + x2 >= c"?

Comment: @Cloudy, default is the square root of the number of variables. so if vars = 10, then mtry is 3. If you tell mtry = 4, then the split will consider 4 vars instead of 3.